# Django REST API login give server error if I set cookie

Tags: python, django, rest, cookies

I'm currently working on a Django web application that involves user authentication. However, I've encountered an issue where the user's login information gets lost whenever I refresh the browser. To address this problem, I decided to implement cookie-based authentication to allow the browser to remember the user's login status. Despite my efforts, I'm facing difficulties in getting this functionality to work correctly.

I changed my code to this:

```
class CustomUserRegistrationView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            response_data = {
                'refresh': str(refresh),
                'access': str(refresh.access_token),
                'message': 'User registered successfully.'
            }
            return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class CustomUserLoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Response({"message": "You are already logged in"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        mobile_number = request.data.get('mobile_number')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        if mobile_number is None or password is None:
            return Response({'error': 'Please provide both mobile number and password'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        
        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(mobile_number=mobile_number)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'message': 'Invalid mobile number or password.'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        if not user.check_password(password):
            return Response({'message': 'Invalid mobile number or password.'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        
        serializer = CustomUserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        user = authenticate(
            mobile_number=serializer.validated_data['mobile_number'],
            password=serializer.validated_data['password']
        )

        if user is None:
            return Response({"error": "Invalid login credentials"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if not user.is_active:
            return Response({'error': 'User account is disabled'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        
        login(request, user)  # Log the user in
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        access_token = refresh.access_token

        
        response_data = {
            "message": "Login successful",
            "refresh_token": str(refresh),
            "access_token": str(refresh.access_token)
        }
    
        
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

To this code, but every time I run this code browser gives server error ((

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

class CustomUserLoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Response({"message": "You are already logged in"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        mobile_number = request.data.get('mobile_number')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        if mobile_number is None or password is None:
            return Response({'error': 'Please provide both mobile number and password'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(mobile_number=mobile_number)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'message': 'Invalid mobile number or password.'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        if not user.check_password(password):
            return Response({'message': 'Invalid mobile number or password.'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        user = authenticate(
            request=request,
            username=user.username,  # Use an appropriate field based on your user model
            password=password
        )

        if user is None:
            return Response({"error": "Invalid login credentials"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if not user.is_active:
            return Response({'error': 'User account is disabled'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        login(request, user)  # Log the user in
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        access_token = refresh.access_token

        response_data = {
            "message": "Login successful",
            "refresh_token": str(refresh),
            "access_token": str(refresh.access_token)
        }

        response = Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        # Set the access token as a cookie in the response
        response.set_cookie('access_token', str(refresh.access_token), httponly=True)

        return response
```

However, I've noticed that despite following these steps, the browser continues to lose the user's login information upon refreshing. I suspect there might be issues with my implementation, such as incorrect usage of the `authenticate()` function, cookie configuration, or a potential problem with my custom user model.

Additionally, I'm planning to integrate Android Java for user login in the future. While focusing on the current browser-based login issue, I want to ensure that the implemented authentication mechanism is compatible with my future plans for Android integration.